# Finder tags on Time Capsule files

Tags: macos, finder, time-capsule, finder-tag

I have a folder with files on my Time Capsule. As I know I can set the tags for files and quickly find all files by tag just clicking on the tag on the sidebar of Finder.

All works fine except the files on Time Capsule.  I can set a tag for a file on Time Capsule, but when I am clicking on the Tag on the Finder's sidebar, Finder don't show me my tagged files.

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: I would guess the files on your Time Capsule are excluded from being indexed by Spotlight, which is necessary for them to show up in a tag search. System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy and verify your Time Capsule is not listed there. If that doesn't resolve it, please specify what Mac and version of OS X you are using.

Comment: Thanks.  This table (Privacy) is empty on my Mac.  I have Macbook Air (middle, 2013) and OS X 10.10.1.  I have tryed `mdutil /Volumes/Data-7 -i on` and `mdutil /Volumes/Data-7 -s` returns `indexed`, but Tags still not working.